# How to separate the date, hour and timezone info using pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm curious about how to use pandas to deal with this sort of info in a .csv file:

2022-08-11 11:50:01 America/Los_Angeles

My goal is to extract the date, hour and minute, and the timezone info for further analysis.

I have tried to lift out the date and time using:
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.date`

but got an error because of the string at the end. Other than extracting the date and time using specific indices, is there any better and quicker way? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas cannot handle a datetime column with different timezones. You can start by splitting the `datetime` and `timezone` in separate columns:

```
df[['datetime', 'timezone']] = df['datetime'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']) # this column now has the datetime64[ns] type
```

Now you are able to do the following:

```
df['date_only'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
```

If you want to express all local date/times in `America/Los_Angeles` time:

```
df['LA_datetime'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['datetime'].tz_localize(tz=x['timezone']).tz_convert('America/Los_Angeles'), axis = 1)
```

You can change `America/Los_Angeles` to the timezone of your liking.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm currently doing the .loc specific indices thing, but this should be a great alternative.