# Timezone data goes lost when transforming data to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, calendar, timezone

I was coding a project on my own which checks my available time slots by directly checking my calendar events using the code down below. For the calendar I used for my daily activities it worked fine (aside from some minor errors), but when I created a new, 'test' calendar with another mail, it showed a particular error. For my normal calendar, there were not issues. But for my 'test' calendar, somehow the timezone information was lost somewhere. The links to the calendars are made so that only the viewer can see whenever I'm busy or not, so I don't mind placing the calendar links I used in this question too.

Basically, the only input the code needs is the link to the calendar, which is a .ics link. The code I made is shown down below:

Imported relevant packages:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from ics import Calendar
from ics import Event
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pytz
```

My code to check my available time slots goes as follows:

```
def check_availability(url):
    c = Calendar(requests.get(url).text)
    events_start=[]
    events_end=[]
    events_avb=[]
    # events_type=[]
    # events_people=[]
    # events_location=[]

    for event in c.events:
        if event.begin.datetime > pytz.UTC.localize(datetime.now()): #Check if event is not in the past
            events_start.append(event.begin.datetime)
            events_end.append(event.end.datetime)
            events_avb.append(event.name)
            #So after this, I will have 3 lists of events that occur after today with start 
            datetime, end datetime and availability (busy/free etc.)

    #         events_type.append(event.categories)
    #         events_people.append(event.attendees)
    #         events_location.append(event.location)

    #events dataframe --> Each row is an event
    # Columns: Start_time, end_time, type, availability, attendees, (location)

    data = {'Start event': events_start  ,
            'End event': events_end ,
            'Availability': events_avb ,
    #         'Type': events_type ,
    #         'People':events_people ,
    #         'Location':events_location
            }  

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df_sorted= df.sort_values(by=['Start event'])
    
#    df_sorted = df_sorted.reset_index()

    return df_sorted, data #, free_timeslots(df_sorted)
  
def free_timeslots(df):
    end_events=[]
    start_next_events=[]
    for i in range(df.shape[0]-1):
        end_events.append(df['End event'].iloc[i])
        start_next_events.append(df['Start event'].iloc[i+1])
    data = {'From': end_events,
    'To': start_next_events
    }
    
    return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So when I want to check my availabily, I let the function return the dataframe with my available timeslots. However, I noticed the timezones had been removed from my second 'test' calendar, (but not from my first, 'normal' calendar?) therefore I tried some things and found out the problem was rooted all the way the beginning of the code where I transformed my data to a dataframe. Therefore, instead of running the normal function, I let check_availabilty(url) return df_sorted and data for each calendar instead, of which the outputs are shown down below:

'Normal calendar'

```
check_availability("https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/4200e0e743594e75ba5eff2c769bee70@student.tue.nl/4e9d194285a34094bd25dae1a423d0b416240567917402426981/calendar.ics")

>>> 

(                  Start event                  End event Availability
 21  2022-05-25 15:45:00+02:00  2022-05-25 16:00:00+02:00         Busy
 3   2022-05-25 20:00:00+02:00  2022-05-25 21:00:00+02:00         Busy
 16  2022-05-26 07:00:00+02:00  2022-05-26 07:30:00+02:00         Busy
 0   2022-05-26 07:30:00+02:00  2022-05-26 08:00:00+02:00         Busy
 1   2022-05-27 07:00:00+02:00  2022-05-27 07:30:00+02:00         Busy
 9   2022-05-27 07:30:00+02:00  2022-05-27 08:00:00+02:00         Busy
 4   2022-05-27 20:00:00+02:00  2022-05-28 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 18  2022-05-28 12:00:00+02:00  2022-05-29 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 24  2022-05-31 08:40:00+02:00  2022-05-31 09:10:00+02:00         Busy
 11  2022-05-31 12:30:00+02:00  2022-05-31 13:30:00+02:00    Tentative
 14  2022-06-01 18:00:00+02:00  2022-06-02 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 12  2022-06-03 00:00:00+00:00  2022-06-08 00:00:00+00:00         Free
 17  2022-06-04 17:00:00+02:00  2022-06-05 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 7   2022-06-18 18:00:00+02:00  2022-06-19 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 20  2022-06-19 00:00:00+00:00  2022-06-20 00:00:00+00:00         Free
 2   2022-06-25 12:00:00+02:00  2022-06-26 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 6   2022-07-06 00:00:00+00:00  2022-07-07 00:00:00+00:00         Free
 5   2022-07-07 12:00:00+02:00  2022-07-07 15:00:00+02:00         Busy
 8   2022-07-08 20:00:00+02:00  2022-07-09 01:00:00+02:00         Busy
 10  2022-07-10 16:00:00+02:00  2022-07-10 23:00:00+02:00         Busy
 22  2022-07-17 10:00:00+02:00  2022-07-17 17:00:00+02:00         Busy
 23  2022-07-25 00:00:00+00:00  2022-08-01 00:00:00+00:00         Free
 13  2022-08-21 13:00:00+02:00  2022-08-21 23:30:00+02:00         Busy
 19  2022-09-16 20:00:00+02:00  2022-09-17 00:00:00+02:00         Busy
 15  2022-10-01 00:00:00+00:00  2022-10-22 00:00:00+00:00         Free,
 {'Start event': [datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 7, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 25, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 18, 18, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 8, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 10, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 31, 12, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 21, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 1, 18, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 7, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 4, 17, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 16, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 15, 45, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 17, 10, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 31, 8, 40, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time'))],
  'End event': [datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 8, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 21, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 15, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 9, 1, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 8, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 10, 23, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 31, 13, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 8, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 21, 23, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 29, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 17, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 16, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 17, 17, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc()),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 31, 9, 10, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time'))],
  'Availability': ['Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Free',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Tentative',
   'Free',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Free',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Free',
   'Busy',
   'Busy',
   'Free',
   'Busy']})
```

'Test' calendar:

```
check_availability("https://outlook.live.com/owa/calendar/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00ba68fe-a5e3-46df-9432-c9df87a861ae/cid-87462FEDF3B21E72/calendar.ics")

>>>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.get_dst_info()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.localize_tso'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timezones.pyx", line 220, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timezones.get_dst_info
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

#(I get this error exactly 14 times)


(          Start event           End event Availability
 0 2022-05-25 14:30:00 2022-05-25 16:00:00         Busy
 2 2022-05-25 19:00:00 2022-05-25 21:00:00         Busy
 1 2022-05-26 07:00:00 2022-05-26 15:00:00         Busy
 6 2022-05-26 19:00:00 2022-05-26 21:00:00         Busy
 4 2022-05-27 10:00:00 2022-05-27 11:00:00         Busy
 3 2022-05-27 13:00:00 2022-05-27 15:00:00         Busy
 5 2022-05-27 17:00:00 2022-05-27 21:00:00         Busy,
 {'Start event': [datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 16, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 9, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 21, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 15, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 12, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 19, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 21, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time'))],
  'End event': [datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 18, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 17, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 25, 23, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 17, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 13, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 27, 23, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')),
   datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 26, 23, 0, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time'))],
  'Availability': ['Busy', 'Busy', 'Busy', 'Busy', 'Busy', 'Busy', 'Busy']})
```

So for the test calendar, the data seems to contain the same information as the normal calendar, but yet acts differently.

Does someone know what is going wrong here? I would gladly appreciate any clues

Kind regards,
Maiky

Comment: your input seems to contain data from different time zones (and UTC), so you should either convert to UTC or a common time zone, e.g. "Europe/Berlin" for CET. That will give you the advantage that pandas can handle date/time with the built-in datetime64[ns] data type-- giving you more options such as the .dt accessor.

Answer (score 0):

When datetimes with multiple timezones are stored in a column, pandas will store this column with the `object` type.
Only if all datetime elements are from the same timezone will the column be stored as `datetime64[ns]`.

In your exemple the error likely occurs when all datetimes are from the same timezone, specifically while converting the datetime objects to `datetime64[ns]`.

To avoid this you can convert the datetimes in your constructor:

```
pd.to_datetime(datetime(2022, 5, 26, 7, 30, tzinfo=tzwin('W. Europe Standard Time')))
```

Or while reading your start/end events, write the datetimes and the timezones in separate columns. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282146/how-to-separate-the-date-hour-and-timezone-info-using-pandas/72285389#72285389) for example.