# pandas cannot conver to datetime object

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file where the a timestamp column is coming with values in the following format: `2022-05-12T07:09:33.727-07:00`

When I try something like:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

It seems to fail silently as the `dtype` of that column is still `object`. I am wondering how I can parse such a value.
Also, what is the strategy so that it remains robust to a variety of input time formats?

Comment: `-07:00` is likely the timezone. If you have different timezones, pandas won't be able to convert the column to datetime type. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72285389/13525512). You'll have to split on`r'(?=[+-]\d\d:)'` (regex) instead of whitespace

Comment: Good shout! It turns out that the timestamp column does have different timezones (which is opening a whole new can of worms on why this should be!)